# Where to find deploy log file for a ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

Where would I find the log file for a ruby on rails application?  I am using capistrano to deploy and it is not deploying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capistrano itself produces no log files - it outputs everything it is doing to the screen:

The app's log file will be in the app's log folder by default.

If using passenger then an app that fails to start will often leave information in apache/nginx's error log

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat of an aside, but you can record your deployments in NewRelic, which is how we keep track of when they occur:

https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/recording-deployments-with-the-ruby-agent